# Trying to read and handle array of class objects from a binary file in C++

Tags: c++, performance, file, class

I have a school project in which I have to create a program which makes use of C++ file handling and classes.

But when I am storing data for month of April and reading it back again in first program run, it shows the data.

But in second program run, when I enter data for the month of may and try to read data for month of April it does not show the values I entered in first program run.

Here is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class money
{
    long double gpay=0.0,bpay=0.0,savings=0.0,groceries=0.0,pf=0.0,npay=0.0,hrent=0.0,
                ins=0.0,edu=0.0,misc=0.0,texp=0.0,med=0.0;


public:
    char name_month[15];
    void getdata()
    {
        cout<<endl<<endl<<"Enter your basic pay : ";
        cin>>bpay;
        cout<<"Enter your gross pay : ";
        cin>>gpay;
        cout<<"Enter your net pay : ";
        cin>>npay;
        cout<<endl<<"Enter house rent (inclusive of water and electricity) : ";
        cin>>hrent;
        cout<<endl<<"Enter expenditure on groceries : ";
        cin>>groceries;
        cout<<endl<<"Enter insurance premium amt (if any) (monthly) : ";
        cin>>ins;
        cout<<endl<<"Enter monthly expense on education (if any) : ";
        cin>>edu;
        cout<<endl<<"Enter medical expense (if any) : ";
        cin>>med;
        cout<<endl<<"Enter any miscellaneous expenditure (bills , transport, etc.) : ";
        cin>>misc;
        pf=0.12*bpay;
        texp=hrent+ins+groceries+edu+med+misc;
        savings=pf+(npay-texp);
    }

    void putdata()
    {
        cout<<endl<<endl<<"Your basic pay : "<<bpay<<endl;
        cout<<"Your gross pay : "<<gpay<<endl;
        cout<<"Your net pay : "<<npay<<endl;
        cout<<endl<<"House rent (inclusive of water and electricity) : "<<hrent<<endl;
        cout<<endl<<"Expenditure on groceries : "<<groceries<<endl;
        cout<<endl<<"Insurance premium amt (monthly) : "<<ins<<endl;
        cout<<endl<<"Monthly expense on education : "<<edu<<endl;
        cout<<endl<<"Medical expense : "<<med<<endl;
        cout<<endl<<"Miscellaneous expenditure (bills , transport, etc.) : "<<misc<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"Your expenditure : "<<texp<<endl;
        cout<<"Your savings from this month : "<<savings<<endl;

    }

        float getexp()
        {
            return texp;
        }
        float getsaving()
        {
            return savings;
        }

}u[12];
int main()
{
    system("color f0");
    int s = sizeof(money),cho=0,x,ans,a,b;
    char choice;
    cout<<endl<<"Enter the number for month whose record you want to enter =>"<<endl<<endl<<"1. April"<<endl
    <<"2. May"<<endl<<"3. June"<<endl<<"4. July"<<endl<<"5. August"<<endl<<"6. September"<<endl<<"7. October"<<endl
    <<"8. November"<<endl<<"9. December"<<endl<<"10. January"<<endl<<"11. February"<<endl<<"12. March"<<endl<<endl;
    cin>>x;
    cout<<endl;
    switch (x)
    {
        case 1 :cout<<"Entering data for month of April";
        break;
        case 2 :cout<<"Entering data for month of May";
        break;
        case 3 :cout<<"Entering data for month of June";
        break;
        case 4 :cout<<"Entering data for month of July";
        break;
        case 5 :cout<<"Entering data for month of August";
        break;
        case 6 :cout<<"Entering data for month of September";
        break;
        case 7 :cout<<"Entering data for month of October";
        break;
        case 8 :cout<<"Entering data for month of November";
        break;
        case 9 :cout<<"Entering data for month of December";
        break;
        case 10 :cout<<"Entering data for month of January";
        break;
        case 11 :cout<<"Entering data for month of February";
        break;
        case 12 :cout<<"Entering data for month of March";
        break;
    }
    u[x-1].getdata();

    ofstream file;
    file.open("calc.dat",ios::out|ios::binary|ios::ate);
    int q=x-1;
    file.seekp(160*q);

    long pos=file.tellp();
    cout<<"before write"<<pos;getch();


    file.write((char*)& u[x-1], sizeof(u[x-1]));
    pos=file.tellp();
    cout<<"   after write"<<pos;getch();
file.close();
    cout<<endl<<"Your total expenditure is : "<<u[x-1].getexp();
    cout<<endl<<endl<<"Your savings are : "<<u[x-1].getsaving()<<" (Total savings include pf amount also)";

    cout<<endl<<endl<<"Do you want to see records of any month ? (y/n)"<<endl;
    cin>>choice;
    do
    {
    if(choice=='y')
    {
        cout<<endl<<"Enter the number for month whose record you want to see =>"<<endl
        <<"1. April"<<endl<<"2. May"<<endl<<"3. June"<<endl<<"4. July"<<endl<<"5. August"<<endl<<"6. September"<<endl<<
        "7. October"<<endl<<"8. November"<<endl<<"9. December"<<endl<<"10. January"<<endl<<"11. February"<<endl<<"12. March"<<endl<<endl;
        cin>>cho;
        switch (cho)
    {
        case 1 :cout<<"Showing data for month of April";
        break;
        case 2 :cout<<"Showing data for month of May";
        break;
        case 3 :cout<<"Showing data for month of June";
        break;
        case 4 :cout<<"Showing data for month of July";
        break;
        case 5 :cout<<"Showing data for month of August";
        break;
        case 6 :cout<<"Showing data for month of September";
        break;
        case 7 :cout<<"Showing data for month of October";
        break;
        case 8 :cout<<"Showing data for month of November";
        break;
        case 9 :cout<<"Showing data for month of December";
        break;
        case 10 :cout<<"Showing data for month of January";
        break;
        case 11 :cout<<"Showing data for month of February";
        break;
        case 12 :cout<<"Showing data for month of March";
        break;
    }

        ifstream ifile;
        int l=cho-1;
        cout<<l;
        ifile.open("calc.dat",ios::in|ios::binary);

        ifile.seekg(160*l);
        long tellsop=ifile.tellg();
        cout<<"before read"<<tellsop<<endl;getch();
        ifile.read((char*)& u[cho-1],sizeof(u[cho-1]));
        tellsop=ifile.tellg();
        cout<<"after read"<<tellsop<<endl;
        u[cho-1].putdata();
    }
    if(choice!='y')
    {
        break;
    }
    cout<<endl<<"Do you want to see more records ? (y/n)";
    cin>>choice;
    }while(choice=='y');
    file.close();


    return 0;
}
```

I entered data for the month of April in first run and when I tried to display it got displayed correctly.

[My first run shows data for April](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je6fW.png)

but on my second run when I entered data for the month of May and tried to read data for the month of April which I stored in the previous program run, the value shown were the default values i.e. 0

[My second run when I entered data for May](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBFCZ.png)

I entered data for month of may and on checking for April it shows 0.

Comment: Please edit your post **with the text of program**, not links to images.  Firewalls can block people's access to your links, and thus won't be able to help you.  Also, don't paste images of your program.  Highlight the text in your editor, copy to clipboard, then paste into your question.

Comment: I seriously do not know how to add code in stack overflow platform

Comment: If you can type in the edit box, you can add the code.  Highlight the code in your IDE and copy (Ctrl-C, or Ctrl-Insert, etc).  Then place the cursor in the edit window of the browser and paste the text (Ctrl-V or Shift-Insert, etc).  Same technique if you were copying code from one file and pasting into another file.

Comment: i tried doing it but only some of code snippets were represented as code and rest all the line were distorted and it would have been difficult for both you and me to understand it....... But thanks anyways

Comment: Select your code in your editor/IDE, press _Tab_ to indent it, copy it and paste it into your answer. With the indention it will be displayed as code (gray background and line breaks will be preserved). See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: thanks a lot howgler.....helped a lot ......would be posting code from here on

Answer (score 0):

use ios::app mode during writing to file.

```
fstream f("file.bin",ios::binary|ios::app);
string msg="my sample msg";

f<<msg;
f.close();

string line;
ifstream fin("file.bin",ios::binary);

if (fin.is_open())
    while ( getline (fin,line) )
        cout << line << '\n';

fin.close();
```

Comment: I tried using ios::app but it made the condition even worse ..... now it is not reading the data even once